# Changes in the null conditional operator in C# 6

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I am reading up on the changes introduced in C# 6.0 and I have a question about null operators.

In C# 6 this expression

```
int? x= y?.length;
```

will be valid if `y` is `null` and return a `null`. No `NullargumentException` will be raised. Which I believe is a good addition to the language. It removes extra checks and ugly looking code.

But in the case of the null conditional operator we might have code like the following

```
int? x= y?.length ?? 0;
```

If `y` is `null` then `0` is returned. What happens though if `length` is null? It returns zero again?

Comment: `length` would be `int` so it will return 0

Comment: Yes. `y?.length` is evaluted first. So: when `y?.length` is `null`, then `(null ?? 0)` evalutes to `0`. I'm not sure only if cast would bee needed: `(int?)0`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal whe don't know wheter `length` is `int` or `int?`. It looks to me that it is `int?` rather.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal for this case it is int?

Comment: @nopeflow That's what I was thinking but I was not 100% sure and could not right code to test it as I do nto have c# 6 currently installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator `??` will return the left hand side expression if the expression is not `null` otherwise the right hand side.

The result type is whatever is on the right side, in your case a `int`.

`y?.length` evaluates to `null` if either `y` is null, or `y.length` is `null`.

In both cases the left hand side of `??` evaluates to `null`, so `0` is returned by `??`.

Comment: My speculations are true then :D